# Why are styles not shown in the browser for this inline element?

Tags: css

Despite that I see they are set correctly in both the **HTML inspector** and the **CSS Rules** portion of the Firefox debugger.

Here is the CSS for the box:

```
.box_background_glass{
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}

/*update - this was an inline element
*/

.i_box{
  width:  300px;
  height:  185px;
  border-radius:  4px;
}
```

Here is the HTML

```
<div id='mi_hold'>
    <div id='mi_box'>
      <div id='mi_about'  class='i_box shadow box_background_glass' >
        <p class='mi_tit large_dark'>About</p>
        <p class='mi_con small_light'> foo
          <br>
        </p>
      </div><!-- mi_about end -->

      // ...snip

    </div><!-- mi_box end -->
    <div id='mi_control' class='radius_all'>
      <p id='mi_cover_l' class='menu_bottom small_dark'>foo; </p>
      <p id='mi_about_l' class='menu_bottom small_dark'>About</p>
      <p id='mi_privacy_l' class='menu_bottom small_dark'>Privacy</p>
      <p id='mi_team_l' class='menu_bottom small_dark'>Contact</p>
      <p id='mi_arc_l' class='menu_bottom small_dark'>Developers</p>
  </div><!-- mi_control end -->
</div><!-- mi_hold end -->
```

Comment: It looks to me like javascript is adding an `opacity: 0;` which would make the element in fact invisible.

Comment: @SanderKoedood — There are multiple elements that are members of the same classes. The highlighted one in the DOM is opacity 0 but the one you can see in the screenshot is not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can see in the screenshot that you have set it to `display: inline`, so `height` and `width` don't apply and the block content busts out of it.

You need `display: block`.

Comment: Setting a border radius, without having a border width/style/color set also makes it hard to debug ;-) Once set, it is easy to see that the inline setting is what is causing the issue.

Comment: @cadegalt — The accepted answer at the other end of the line is nonsense, and the question is irrelevant since you aren't (and shouldn't) using absolute positioning.

Answer (score 0):

Set `display: block;` for `mi_about` and you should see the glass box.